# When I try to send data to the server, I do not get the result expected

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I have a Jquery function that is using getJson. I am trying to form something like www.mysite.com/?state=oregon. According to Jquery ("Data that is sent to the server is appended to the URL as a query string..."), but I get all the values in the json data. What I am doing wrong.

Here is my code

```
function changeLine(line){

    $('#table_lines').html('');


    $.getJSON("../index.php", {, line}, function(data){
        var line_data = '';
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            line_data += '<tr id="' +value.line_id+'">';

            line_data += '<td>' + otherValueTime(value.MatchTime)+'</td>';
            line_data += '<td>' + value.home+'</td>';
            line_data += '<td>' + value.away+'</td>';
            for(i=0; i < value.Cases.length; i++){
                console.log(value.Cases[i].CaseType + ' ' + value.Cases[i].CaseAway + ' ' + value.Cases[i].CaseHome);
                if(value.Cases[i].CaseType === "Game"){
                    line_data += '<td>' + value.Cases[i].CaseAway +'</td>';
                    line_data += '<td>' + value.Cases[i].Total +'</td>';
                    line_data += '<td>' + value.Cases[i].Over +'</td>';
                }


            }


        });
        $('#table_lines').append(line_data);
    });
}
```

On the line with this code "{, line}", I tried putting the key value from the json array, like {id: line}. What I want to do is to get a group of cases according to the key.

I would like to know how you do that. I want to change it according to the option value. I do get data from the server, but I get all the data. Here is how I call that function

```
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str = $( this ).val();


      $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "../index.php",
              data: { 'id' : str }

        })
    });
    changeLinea(str);
})
.change();
```

Comment: @Peter, any comment?